# recombine string columns based on another columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame with 3 columns :

```
id  product_id  is_opt
1   1           False
1   2           False
1   3           True
1   4           True
2   5           False
2   6           False
2   7           False
3   8           False
3   9           False
3   10          True
```

I want to transform this DataFrame this way :

- For a set of rows that shares the same `id`, if all rows are `is_opt = False`, then the set of rows stays unchanged. For example, the rows with `id = 2` do not change.
- For a set of rows that shares the same `id`, if at least one row is `is_opt = True`, then we apply this transformation:

  - All rows that are `is_opt = True` stay unchanged.
  - All rows that are `is_opt = False` take at the end of their `product_id` all the `product_id`s of the rows that are `is_opt = True`. If there are n rows `is_opt = True`, then 1 row with `is_opt = False` gives n rows. For exemple, the first row `[1, 1, False]` gives 2 rows `[1, 1-3, False]` and `[1, 1-4, False]`.

The expected output for the example is:

```
id  product_id
1   1-3
1   1-4
1   2-3
1   2-4
1   3
1   4
2   5
2   6
2   7
3   8-10
3   9-10
3   10
```

`is_opt` column has been droped in the expected result.

Can you help me with a way to get this result in an efficient set of operations ? It is straightforward with some for loops but I would like something efficient because the DataFrames in production are huge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom function and [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product

def combine(df):
    if df['is_opt'].any():
        a = df.loc[~df['is_opt'], 'product_id']
        b = df.loc[df['is_opt'], 'product_id']
        l = ['-'.join(map(str, p)) for p in product(a, b)]
        return pd.Series(l+b.tolist())
    return df['product_id']

out = df.groupby('id').apply(combine).droplevel(1).reset_index(name='product_id')
```

output:

```
    id product_id
0    1        1-3
1    1        1-4
2    1        2-3
3    1        2-4
4    1          3
5    1          4
6    2          5
7    2          6
8    2          7
9    3       8-10
10   3       9-10
11   3         10
```